# Get the minimum value of an object in d3.min

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I get the maximum value for the key "sample"?

I can use `d3.max(myData)` to get the maximum of an array like `[1,2,3]`. For my more complex example, I can use an accessor function to get the values out of `myData`. What does this accessor function look like?

```
var myData = [
  { type: "a", sample: 28, population: 32},
  { type: "b", sample: 24, population: 19},
  { type: "c", sample: 19, population: 23},
  { type: "d", sample: 29, population: 26}
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accessor function will be evaluated for each each array element, with the element being passed as the first argument.  With that in mind, you can do the following:

```
d3.max(myData, function(d) {
  return d.sample;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

As an extension to the already provided answer, I want to add two things. First being very obvious - there is an equivalent approach to obtaining the minimum value. The second is something that I have done myself before when assessing extreme values for computing the domain and range is this.

```
var min = d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.val; });
var max = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.val; });
var colors = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([min, max])
  .range(["blue", "red"]);
```

However, there is a function returning **both**. It is just named in an clumsy and not intuitive way, IMnHO - [*d3.extent*](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#extent). It allows you for omitting both of the lines for calculating the extremes and looks quite neat.

```
var colors = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.val; }))
  .range(["blue", "red"]);
```